# Application crashes when I click the onmylocationbutton clicked

Tags: android, dictionary, nullpointerexception, crash

from some reason, when I click on the onmylocationbutton clicked(google maps function) it crashes to me. I don't understand why. I looked in the Internet to check what the problem with the logcat but from some reason I can't get it. what should I change in my code?

MainActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] NavigationDrawerItems;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    public GoogleMap map;
    public Location location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmap);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        NavigationDrawerItems = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.navigationdraweritems);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // location stuff

        final GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // the location manager and the Criteria to find the right source for
        // location
        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        // location manager
        final android.location.Location location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,
                        false));

        if (location != null) {
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
                    location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 10));
        }
        // class that gets the new location
        class NewLocation implements LocationListener {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                location.getLatitude();
                location.getLongitude();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
        }
        // end of the class the gets the new location

        map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
                // if the Gps is off it openes a dialog to turn it off
                if (!locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    buildAlertMessageNoGps();
                } else {
                    // if it on, animates to the current position
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                                    .getLongitude()), 15));
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        // closes on create
    }
```

there is a little bit more code after it. but it doesn't relate to it and works fine.

My LogCat:

```
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at nir.rauch.flantir.MainActivity$1.onMyLocationButtonClick(MainActivity.java:109)
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$2.onMyLocationButtonClick(Unknown Source)
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.m$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:347)
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at foj.a(SourceFile:81)
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at lxw.onClick(Unknown Source)
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
06-04 13:29:30.566: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @SimplePlan wouln't it crash here         map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); is map was null?

Comment: remove this ' final GoogleMap' from your map object initialization

Comment: Is location object null?

Comment: @Mighter Crashed not by location. @n is your Google play services properly configure?

Comment: Indicate  line 106 in `MainActivity.java`

Comment: @AndroSelva it must be final if I want to call my map to animate in the mylocationbuttonclicked function.

Comment: @Mighter no, as you see I call my location when my gps is on(in the inner class) , and in the begining if the location is known and the gps is on, it still not animates the camera to the position of the location.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your findViewById returns null in your map variable.

Try to use MapView

```
MaoView mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
GoogleMap map = mapView.getMap();
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Comment: but my map is as a fragment, not as a view.

Comment: You can not put your map as a view inside fragment? I think is more correctly.